# When to default to main function in C

Tags: c, variables

Working my way through [Big Nerd Ranch Obj-C Book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321706285).

Challenge in chapter on functions asks for you to write function that given two angles of a triangle will return the third. Simple enough.

My code (which works):

```
#include <stdio.h>

float triangle(float angleA, float angleB) {
    float angleC = 180 - (angleA + angleB);
    printf("The third angle of the triangle is %f degrees", angleC);
    return angleC;
 }

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    float angleA = 30.0;
    float angleB = 60.0;
    triangle(angleA, angleB);
    return 0;
 }
```

I declare the float `angleC` within `triangle()`.

The book's answer has `angleC` called within `main()`

Book answer:

```
 float triangle(float angleA, angleB) {
       return 180 - (angleA + angleB); 
  }
  int main (int argc, constant char * argv[]) {
       float angleA = 30.0; 
       float angleB = 60.0; 
       float angleC = triangle(angleA, angleB);
       printf("The third angle of the triangle is %f degrees.", angleC); 
       return 0; 
   }
```

**Does it matter where I declare var `angleC`? Is there a difference between our two versions of code, or is one better then the other?**

Comment: feel free to edit title of this question. I wasn't sure how to properly label.

Comment: Feel free to do whatever you want. Personally, I would prefer the book solution and keep your function clean of any writing to stdout etc

Comment: At the end of the day, this question is pretty irrelevant.  Are you really going to be using Objective-C's `main` function?  The chances of you touching main in an `iOS` or `OSX` app are extraordinarily rare.  This is a structured programming practice problem for an object-oriented language... and really, this isn't even ObjC.  It's just C.

Comment: This quotesn't isn't really objective-c specific, but you will find, at least on iOS, that almost all objective-c programs just create an autorelease pool in main, and call `UIApplicationMain`.  Initialization and such will be done in your App Delegate.

Comment: @nhgrif I see where you're coming from, but just want to make sure I cover all my bases in C before moving on.

Comment: That's fine... but this particular question is really heavily targeted toward structured programming concepts, and Objective-C is object-oriented.  As someone who codes in Objective-C every single day, I'm telling you not to free too much about this and worry more about object-oriented concepts.

Comment: This is plain C, nothing else. You coudl do both, declare angleC in the function AND in main. But that could be confusing for new students. In both examples there is no need for a variable angleC at all. But in both cases it makes the code more readable and therefore maintainable.

Comment: It is perfectly ok to learn the C basics first and then learn the advantages of an object oriented C extension. That helps a lot. It is an essential part of that learning courve to understand, what of these is plain C and what Objective-C adds to the value. Learn separating them. Without understnding, what is which you will not be able to procude good readable Obj-C code, nor will you be able to brake the rules and go for plain C only when it is really advantageous to doing so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the difference in terms of *responsibility*. Should it really be the responsibility of the `triangle()` function to print the result? What would happen if you wanted to reuse this function for another purpose that didn't require printing the result?

In the case of this specific problem, both solutions are equivalent. But the book's solution is more easily generalizable and reusable, which is a plus.